# Trying to upgrade Python 3.6 version to Python 3.8.10

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade, python-3.8

I am trying to upgrade my Python version from 3.6.4 to 3.8.10

Below are the steps i followed :

1. wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/Python-3.8.10.tgz
2. tar -xf Python-3.8.10.tgz
3. cd Python-3.8.10
4. ./configure --enable-optimizations
5. make -j 4

when trying to install python binaries with command "sudo make altinstall"
getting errors,
But if i am trying the same process with version 3.8.0, all the above steps work.

Can anyone guide how to troubleshoot the error?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vDHs.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post text as a screenshot. Instead, just copy-paste that text directly.